# Pull on - premise active directory data using Azure data factory

Tags: azure, entra-id

I am fairly new to the Azure development world. I have been tasked to integrate an on-premise active directory with the cloud Azure SQL database( Managed Instance).

The task is to pull the identity data from on-prem AD and pump it into a SQL table in the managed SQL instance on Azure. Can ADF connect on-prem AD with cloud Azure SQL?.

Can someone show me some pointers on this? please

Comment: Why was this downvoted?

Answer (score 0):

You're being downvoted most likely because you haven't done your homework.

You'll need to sync the on-prem accounts from the Active Directory Domain Controller (AD DC) to Azure Active Directory (AAD), this can be done by using any of the following:

- **Azure AD Connect**: this give you so many options and total control on how to sync your local AD objects to the cloud, it's a mess to learn if you're very new to the cloud: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/whatis-azure-ad-connect
- **Azure AD Cloud Sync**: the new replacment of Azure AD Connect, it's much to install and use compared to Azure AD Connect: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/cloud-sync/what-is-cloud-sync

Once you sync your accounts to the cloud, you should be able to add them to SQL: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/authentication-aad-overview